# Square API: How to keep track of orders that weren't charged

Tags: api, square

I want to keep track of orders for events using Square, but I'd like the user to have the option of paying at the door of the event. I noticed in the API documentation, the batch-retrieve endpoint only returns charged orders. Is there any way around this?

So far, I was thinking of keeping track of customers and keeping track of unpaid orders in the notes. However, this might be a bit messy. Does anyone have a simpler solution?

Answer (score 0):

Square APIs are designed to track paid orders. There is not a way to track unpaid orders at this time.

We are constantly improving the product based on feedback like this, so I’ll be sure to share your thoughts with the API team.

Comment: I appreciate it!